# Exchange Web Services (EWS) Limitations

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

Recently I developed an interface in C# to access Outlook calendars. Now I am developing the same functionality to connect to an EWS.

What I not fully understand is the signature of some of the methods: Like for instance if I want all appointments from my calendar why do I have to set how many appointments I expect etc?

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(30);
const int NUM_APPTS = 5;

// Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);
```

I personally prefer the way they handled it in the Outlook assembly. There I could simply iterate through all calendar folders, add string queries if I wanted to and didn't have to specify how many appointments I expect etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: As Robbie already says, it is most likely to allow a better performance guarantee for both the Exchange server **and** your application (imagine the SOAP message size if you pulled down 10K appointments in one go). But unless the EWS designers drop by to spill the beans (not likely), this question is not really answerable in its current form. I voted to close it because of that.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a performance thing.  People can have LOTS of appointments in a given calendar.  Sometimes you need or want to limit how many are returned.  This is exemplified on your phone.  Normally your phone defaults to only syncing mail and appointments that are a few days old, or a certain number of them.

Answer (score 0):

That's not so much the expected number of Appointments, but the max number for that CalendarView. Strangely enough, the CalendarView won't allow you to page through the results. You'd need an ItemView in conjunction with a SearchFilter (if needed) to do that. Then you can check for more Items and get the next batch if more are available until there are no more, which sounds a fair bit like what you're looking for. Alternatively, if you really want ALL Appointments, you could use something like ExchangeService.syncFolderItems to pull as many as 512 at a time.

However, like the others have said, it's likely more about performance. SOAP is already a bit bloated as it is, and if you wanted to get a huge number of Appointments while requesting a ton of properties...well, it's easy to see how that could get pretty ugly, pretty fast, both for Exchange and the network. Putting a cap on the number to be retrieved isn't really a bad idea when you realize just how humungous a calendar folder can get.